# ScrollView in Fragment does not scroll when the soft keyboard shows up

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview, android-scroll

I have a `Fragment` and there is a `ScrollView` in that `Fragment`.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.tatar.mobile.widget.CardSelectionView
            android:id="@+id/card_selection_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:accountRightTextView1="@string/available"
            app:accountTitleTextView="@string/from"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/gray.light"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_selection_view" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/type_spinner"
            style="@style/spinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line_text_view" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/company_spinner"
            style="@style/spinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/type_spinner" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_form_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_spinner" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/installment_spinner"
            style="@style/spinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dynamic_form_container" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continue_button"
            style="@style/action_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/continue_button_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/installment_spinner" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The `LinearLayout` with the id of `dynamic_form_container` in that `ScrollView` contains form input fields which will are populated via a web service call and there might be up to 6-7 input fields depending on the parameters sent to web service. So, height of the form is kind of high and that is where the problem starts. When I try to enter something to an input field, soft keyboard shows up and some of the other input fields stay under the soft keyboard and scrolling is not possible.

I tried to put this to manifest for the `Activity` of that `Fragment` but it did not help.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

I want to be able to scroll when the soft keyboard shows up. How can I fix that issue ?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

in `onCreateView` method worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for this problem [here,](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/aa9136fb4f5b3a80460fe5f47213985026d20c88/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/util/KeyboardUtil.java) include this class in your project.
And add this following line in onCreate of activity that contains fragment.

`new KeyboardUtil(this,findViewById(R.id.fragment));`

Comment: This works in every situation, just pass your view and it will work. I tried with BottomSheetDialog which has one editText and button , and it worked there too

Answer (score -1):

Hello Please refer below code

this is work for me..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.Activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```